# Count multiple columns with unique value

Tags: mysql

Table A:

```
id        name        desc
--------------------------------
1        abc        something

2        xyz        something
```

Table B:

```
id        nameB        descB        tableA(fk)
-----------------------------------------------
1        ghj        something          1

2        jkl        somethingxyz       1

3        sdf        somesdf            2

4        dfg        somedfg            2
```

I was able to produce output like

TableA.name   TableB.name - Count(TableB.name)

```
abc              ghj - 1
abc              jkl - 1
xyz              sdf - 1
xyz              dfg - 1
```

But i want something like this

TableA.name   TableB.name - Count(TableB.name)

```
abc              ghj - 1, jkl - 1
xyz              sdf - 1, dfg - 1
```

1 is count

Pls help with mysql query.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `GROUP_CONCAT` function with `GROUP BY`

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT A.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b.nameB,'-',cnt) SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  tableA,nameB,COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM B
    GROUP BY tableA,nameB
) b ON A.id = b.tableA
GROUP BY A.name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fa557/2/0)**:

```
| name | GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b.nameB,'-',cnt) SEPARATOR ',') |
|------|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  abc |                                         ghj-1,jkl-1 |
|  xyz |                                         dfg-1,sdf-1 |
```

Comment: will it be same for sqlite?

Comment: Almost the same but it is a little difference on `concat` string syntax https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cAbFkvTNJJgRYjYYvEbPxe/0

Comment: What if i have single table?